# Verify if a string and an integer number is a palindrome using functions (C++)

Tags: c++, string, function, loops, input

I am writing a code that gets 2 inputs, one is a string and the other is an integer. It uses 2 overloaded functions to print the reverse of each input. What I want it to do is for the code to validate each input to see if it is a palindrome or not but I cannot seem to figure out a way to make the reverse variable a separate variable and compare it with the user input.

This is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h> 

using namespace std;

void reverse(string s);

void reverse(int x);


int main() {

    string str;

    int x;

    cout<<"Enter a string: "<< endl;
    cin>> str;

   reverse(str);
   
   cout<<"Enter an integer: "<< endl;
    cin>> x;

   reverse(x);

    return 0;
}

void reverse(string s){

    int x = s.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < x / 2; i++){
        swap(s[i], s[x - i - 1]);
    }

    cout<<s<< endl;


}

void reverse(int x){

   int reversedNumber = 0, remainder;

    while(x != 0) {
        remainder = x%10;
        reversedNumber = reversedNumber*10 + remainder;
        x /= 10;
    }

    cout << reversedNumber;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reverse iterators to help you with this task (`std::string::rbegin` returns a reverse iterator that points to the end of the string). `std::to_string` allows you to convert you number to a string. There's no need to write your own function. Here is an example:

```
bool is_palindrome(const std::string &s)
{
    return std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size()/2, s.rbegin());
}

bool is_palindrome(const unsigned int i)
{
    auto s = std::to_string(i);
    return std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size()/2, s.rbegin());
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int number = 112343211;
    std::string s = "abcdedcba";

    std::cout << s << " is palindrome " 
              << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome(s) << "\n";
    std::cout << number << " is palindrome " 
              << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome(number) << "\n";
}
```

Note that I have used unsigned ints for simplicity. If you want signed ints, you have to take care of the sign as well.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9TP7hTedP).

Answer (score 1):

Your existing functions *print* their result (by streaming to `std::cout`).  To do anything more useful, you'll want to *return* the value.

For example:

```
std::string reverse(std::string s)
{
    auto x = s.length();
    for (std::size_t i = 0;  i < x / 2;  ++i) {
        swap(s[i], s[x - i - 1]);
    }
    // Return the value for caller to use
    return s;
}
```

Or more succinctly:

```
std::string reverse(const std::string& s)
{
    return {s.rbegin(), s.rend()};
}
```

Then your `main()` can use tests such as

```
if (str == reverse(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Double the speed by reversing the last half of the input and checking it against the first half of the input.

Then decide whether checking char by char is faster than using a "reverse" function.

Perhaps something like this (plz excuse any syntax errors):

```
int len = s.length()
int mid = len / 2;
for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++){
    if (s[i] != s[x - len - 1]) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Then consider using pointers, which may be implemented better:

```
int len = s.length()
int mid = len / 2;
char *a = &s;
char *z = &s[len - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++){
    if (*a++ != *z--) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

(Is there a construct for "repeat N times?"; that would eliminate the need for an explicit `i`.)

Or maybe you can say `while (a < z)`:

```
while (a++ < z--) {
    if (*a != *z) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```